# Prolog - Check user input

Tags: io, prolog

Hi folks,

I was wondering if there's a simple way to check what the user typed in in SWI-Prolog. What I do is the following:

```
:- read(Term),
   Term = 'A' -> doSomeStuff, !;
   (Term = 'B' -> doOtherStuff, !;
   (Term = 'C' -> doSomething)).
```

My aim is to do a certain action when the user types in the character A, another when the input is B, and so on... But my code seems not to work. could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a head in your clause, e.g.

```
do :- read(Term),
    (Term = 'A' -> doA, !;
    (Term = 'B' -> doB, !;
    (Term = 'C' -> doC))).

doA :- writeln('DoA').
doB :- writeln('DoB').
doC :- writeln('DoC').
```

Then, call `?- do.`, and type `'A'. <enter>`.

It is easier to use simple constants:

```
do2 :- read(Term),
    (Term = a -> doA, !;
    (Term = b -> doB, !;
    (Term = c -> doC))).
```

Then, call `?- do2.`, and type `a. <enter>`.

Comment: Hey thanks I checked out your code, but when I call do2. and type in c. I get DoB. True. Do know why?

Comment: The outmost brackets were missing. I added them now, and it is working.

Comment: Oh true, I hadn't noticed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It works, if you type `'A'.<Enter>` at the prompt.